# Unable to log in with default 'test' accounts

Tags: docker, authentication, authorization, azerothcore

I'm running AzerothCore in Docker but am unable to sign in with any of the test accounts. I am using the default password of 'a' and have not changed any of the passwords.

When trying to log in on the WotLK client, I get the 'the information you have entered is not valid' box pop up. I can see from my authserver log that it is receiving the username I put in:

```
Added realm "AzerothCore" at 127.0.0.1:3306.
Authserver listening to 0.0.0.0:3724
'172.18.0.1:56942' Accepting connection
[4 ms] SQL(p): DELETE FROM ip_banned WHERE unbandate<>bandate AND unbandate<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
[4 ms] SQL(p): SELECT * FROM ip_banned WHERE ip = '172.18.0.1'
[0 ms] SQL(p): SELECT a.id, a.locked, a.lock_country, a.last_ip, aa.gmlevel, a.salt, a.verifier, a.token_key FROM account a LEFT JOIN account_access aa ON (a.id = aa.id) WHERE a.username = 'TEST1'
[AuthChallenge] Account 'TEST1' is not locked to ip
[AuthChallenge] Account 'TEST1' is not locked to country
[1 ms] SQL(p): UPDATE account_banned SET active = 0 WHERE active = 1 AND unbandate<>bandate AND unbandate<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
[0 ms] SQL(p): SELECT bandate, unbandate FROM account_banned WHERE id = 1 AND active = 1
```

I have also tried changing my authserver.conf file to set `WrongPass.Logging = 1` but neither my log or database reflect a failed login attempt.

I think the fact that it's telling me the account test1 is not locked to an IP or country means it is successfully communicating with the database, but I can't figure out what my problem is here. Any help in understanding what's going on here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also unable to log in with "test1" and "a", but it is quite easy to reset the passwords.

In your worldserver console, paste this in:

```
account set password test1 thisisthenewpassword thisisthenewpassword
account set password test2 thisisthenewpassword thisisthenewpassword
account set password test3 thisisthenewpassword thisisthenewpassword
account set password test4 thisisthenewpassword thisisthenewpassword
account set password test5 thisisthenewpassword thisisthenewpassword
account set password test6 thisisthenewpassword thisisthenewpassword
account set password test7 thisisthenewpassword thisisthenewpassword
account set password test8 thisisthenewpassword thisisthenewpassword
account set password test9 thisisthenewpassword thisisthenewpassword
account set password test10 thisisthenewpassword thisisthenewpassword
```

You can also create a new account for yourself with full GM privileges with these commands:

```
account create yourusername yourpassword
account set gmlevel yourusername 3 -1
```

Comment: Perfect - this worked! Thank you!    
For other noobs stumbling through this like myself (running this on Windows 10), I opened up Git Bash and attached to the worldserver container by entering:  
```winpty docker attach azerothcore-wotlk_ac-worldserver_1```    
Only change I hade to make to chute's commands was prefixing a dot:  
```.account set password test1 a a```